# gradient instead of solid colors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not entirely sure why ggplot is using a gradient for the legend instead of individual points to show the differences.  How can I use two different colors to show the different relationships?

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(1944L, 1945L, 1946L, 1947L, 1947L, 1948L, 
1948L, 1949L, 1949L, 1950L), state = c("montana", "montana", 
"montana", "montana", "nebraska", "montana", "nebraska", "montana", 
"nebraska", "montana"), x = c(28, 26, 25, 27, 49, 39, 57.3, 38, 
55, 41), value = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)), .Names = c("year", 
"state", "x", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"))

ggplot(dat, aes(year, x)) + geom_point(aes(color = value))
```

[image]

Comment: Because `value` is numeric, not a factor. You could change it to `ggplot(dat, aes(year, x)) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(value)))`, or do `dat$value <- factor(dat$value)` beforehand.

Comment: Ugh....factors.  Thanks!  @DavidRobinson I changed it to a factor and am getting `Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint,  : 
  object 'value' not found`

Comment: It works for me, just as @DavidRobinson suggested: `ggplot(dat, aes(year, x)) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(value)))`

Comment: It works in your above code; perhaps you are running it on different data